# Como calcular o número de vezes uma palavra aparece dentro de uma frase

Tags: c, string, funções

estou tentando criar um código no qual eu tenho que contar o número de vezes que uma palavra aparece dentro de uma frase, porém, após muito se pesquisar e procurar sobre, só consigo achar códigos que utilizam da função fgets, queria saber se vocês saberiam por qual outra coisa, eu poderia substituir o fgets e ainda funcionaria o todo.
Esse é o código que eu desenvolvi por enquanto :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

char frase[250];
char palavra[50];
int i;
int j = 0;
int count = 0;

    printf( "escveva uma frase: " );
    scanf( "%[^\n]", frase );
    printf( "escreve uma palavra: " );
    scanf( "%s", palavra );

for(int i = 0; frase[i] != '\0'; i++)

    if (palavra[j] == frase[i])
    {
        j += 1;
        if (palavra[j] == '\0')
        {
            count += 1;
            j == 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        j = 0;
    }

    printf( "count = %d\n", count);


    return 0;

}
```

além de tudo, acredito que estou realizando algo errado na parte do for ou de outra parte, pois não estou conseguindo chegar no resultado que queria , mas não consigo compreender onde posso estar errando. Se puderem me ajudar a entender o meu erro, e qual outra coisa além do fgets poderia ser utilizado, eu ficaria muito grato. Além disso, acredito que tenha que colocar algumas strings, como 'strlen', porém só aprendi a utliza- lá com caracteres

Comment: Várias coisas erradas. Começa com a confusão entre o operador de atribuição `=` e o operador de comparação para igualdade `==`. Não utilize o `&` na função scanf para leitura de string.

Comment: Obrigadoooooo, agora consegui!! Não tava entendendo o motivo do erro, e agora deu certo

Answer (score 2):

## Repetições de uma Palavra

Para conseguir o número de repetições você pode pesquisar na string base uma outra string alvo, e isso é exatamente o que a função `strstr()` da biblioteca `string.h` faz (vide [strstr](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/), em inglês). Embora a função encontre apenas a primeira ocorrência, você pode repetir o processo até chegar ao fim da string por meio de um `while` checando se a função não retornou um ponteiro nulo (sinal de que não encontrou mais a string alvo, necessita da inclusão da biblioteca `stdlib.h`), porém, é necessário que, a cada busca da função, você incremente o ponteiro da string alvo, isso dará a impressão de que ela está encolhendo, mas na verdade você só está mudando a indicação de onde ela começa para que a `strstr()` possa continuar de onde parou. Veja o seguinte código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char * frase = "todo mes, todo dia, todo minuto, todo segundo\0";
    char * inicio_frase = frase;
    char * busca = "todo\0";
    int repeticoes = 0;
    do
    {
        frase = strstr(frase, busca);
        if(frase != NULL)
        {
            repeticoes++;
            printf("Achou: %s\n", frase);
        }
        frase++;
    } while(strstr(frase, busca) != NULL);
    frase = inicio_frase;
    printf("Resultados ===================================\n");
    printf("Frase: %s\n", frase);
    printf("Busca: %s\n", busca);
    printf("Repetições da Busca na Frase: %d\n", repeticoes);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Alternativa à fgets()

É divulgado que a função `gets()` é perigosa e não deve ser usada porque não tem tratamento para vazamento de memória por leitura excessiva (vide [gets é de uso arriscado](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gets-is-risky-to-use/), em inglês). A alternativa mais segura e prática à `gets()` é justamente a `fgets()` porque ela só lerá a entrada de caracteres até o limite estabelecido. Entretanto, não sei se você tem alguma restrição MUITO específica com esse código para não usar a `fgets()`, então você pode implementar sua própria função de leitura de linha:

```
void ler_linha(char * string_recipiente, int tamanho_maximo)
{
    char entrada = '\0';
    int posicao = 0;
    do
    {
        entrada = getchar();
        if(entrada != '\n')
            string_recipiente[posicao] = entrada;
        posicao++;
    } while(entrada != '\n' && posicao < (tamanho_maximo - 1));
    string_recipiente[posicao] = '\0';
}
```

## O filtro [^\n] é perigoso

Assim como usar `gets()` é perigoso, usar `scanf()` com o filtro `[^\n]` também é pois não há qualquer tratamento de limite, trazendo de volta todos os malefícios de `gets()`.

Answer (score 0):

teu erro tá nessa linha:

```
  if (palavra[j] = frase[i])
```

tá atribuindo, não comparando, o operador que você quer é ==

```
  if (palavra[j] == frase[i])
```

E na hora da leitura para strings não precisa do &. Teu compilador provavelmente deve estar dando warning sobbre isso.